# Updating a databound value in the parent component?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

> Assuming that there some event that will call the showEditPage function. Which will update the value of isEditPageVisible.

> Index Base class

```
    public abstract class IndexBase : ComponentBase
    {
        protected bool isEditPageVisble = false;
          
        public void showEditPage(){
               isEditPageVisble != isEditPageVisble;
        }
     }
```

> How would I get it right to update the value of isEditPageVisble in the Index component as well
> when someEditPageEvent is called?

> ```
>   Edit component
> ```

```
    @page "/Edit/{isEditPageVisble}"
    @inherits Project.IndexBase
    @using Project.Model;
    
    @if (isEditPageVisble)
    {
        <EditPage @bind-isVisible="isEditPageVisble"></EditPage>
    }
```

> ```
>   Edit base class
> ```

```
    public abstract class EditBase : IndexBase
    {
         [Parameter]
         public bool isEditPageVisble { get; set; }
         [Parameter]
         public EventCallback<bool> isEditPageVisbleChanged { get; set; }


        protected async Task ChangeValueAsync()
        {  
            await isEditPageVisbleChanged .InvokeAsync(isEditPageVisble );
        }

       public void someEditPageEvent(){
         isEditPageVisble = false;
       }

    }
```

> ```
> Edit component
> EditPage.razor
> ```

```
<SomeComponent Visible="isEditPageVisble"></SomeComponent>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a State/Notification Service.  Here's a simple example for your question.

```
using System;

namespace StackOverflow.Answers.Data
{
    public class PageStateService
    {

        public bool IsEditPageVisible
        {
            get => _isEditPageVisible;
            set
            {
                if (value != _isEditPageVisible)
                {
                    IsEditPageVisible = value;
                    EditPageVisibilityChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
        }
        private bool _isEditPageVisible;

        public event EventHandler EditPageVisibilityChanged;
    }
}
```

Register as a scoped service, and inject it into the components that need to use it.  If you want to update a component when `IsEditPageVisible` gets change, wire up an event handler to the `EditPageVisibilityChanged`.

It should look like this:

```
private void OnEditPageVisibilityChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   => StateHasChanged();
```